# A way to shorten this code

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is there any way I can shorten this code? 
The only difference is that I want at index 0 to display 'All' instead of array value.

Or maybe multiple condition? like at index = 0, do this, index which is %2, do this, and last index, do this?

I also found the same solution.
I got another problem now,

I want to choose between two function in a onClick.

```
<a onClick={()=>{AddNewBookmark(userId, newsId); this.changeBookmarkState(isBookmarked, bookmarkIndex);}}>
```

I want is index == 0 to use AddNewBookmark(userId, newsId) or if index == 1 then use RemoveBookmark(userId, newsId).

```
<a onClick={()=>{ index == 0 ? AddNewBookmark(userId, newsId) : 
 RemoveBookmark(userId, newsId); this.changeBookmarkState(isBookmarked, 
 bookmarkIndex);}}>
```

I want the changebookmarkstate to be included no matter what index value.

My attempt didnt work somehow. Any suggestion?

Comment: call API which will delete a record from DB

Comment: don't reedit completly questions - delete and create new one

Comment: You may be better off asking this kind of question at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) in the future. It's not off-topic here, but that site is dedicated to improving already working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all you're doing is changing what gets rendered in the span, you can do your logic in JSX inside the span

This should work:

```
isFiltered[index] && (
   <div key={index}>
     <span>{index == 0 ? "All" : category['Name']}</span>              
   </div>        
);
```

You could also extract this logic into a function, and then call the function in the span. This would be cleaner if you end up wanting to display a bunch of different results in that span. Something like this:

```
helperFucntion(index: number) => (
   index == 0 ? "All" : category['Name']
)

isFiltered[index] && (
   <div key={index}>
     <span>{helperFunction(index)}</span>              
   </div>        
);
```

Comment: Does this work to choose function ?

What is the == ?: operator called?

Comment: its a ternary operator.  Same result as using: `if (index == 0) {return "All"} else {return category['Name']}`

Answer (score 1):

The shortest form of your code could be like this:

```
isFiltered[index] && return (
          <div key={index}>
              <span">{ index ? "ALL" : category['Name'] }</span>              
         </div>        
);
```

Comment: It will ignore first category name on index 0

Comment: I don't know about the business logic, I've just shortened the Khoa's codes

Comment: I just want for the first column for example to display "all" and the rest category name.

This means that I want it to choose "All" for index 0 and the rest 'name'

Comment: Change the template like this: `<span">{ index ? "ALL" + category['Name'] : category['Name'] }</span>`

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems incomplete so I can't be sure but you can use following, based upon your need.

You can insert a new index in start of array.

```
isFiltered.unshift['All'];

if (isFiltered[index]){
    return (
        <div key={index}>
            <span>{ category['Name']}</span>              
        </div>        
    );                   
}
```